# how to get members' info by using group id in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

Here is a group A. I want to extract the members' group information as the training data set.

For example, group A has a list of 400 members and each member joins a number of different groups.

How can I get the members' information from the group? Can I get members' information by simply using the group id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the group endpoint using the graph api...

`https://graph.faecbook.com/GROUP_ID/members`

This will return (quoting [facebook docuemntation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/)) :

> All of the users who are members of this group (can only currently return the first 500 members).

You will have to use a valid access token and you will only be able to retrieve one if you are administering the group.